# Program not running on some IDE's, issue with classes

Tags: c++, oop

Can someone help me find the issue in my code here?
I keep getting an error that just says program terminated.  It runs on certain ide's but not others, and it hurts because I felt like I was starting to grasp the concepts of OOP, but guess not.  The main idea of the program is to read the shape data into a pointer array and then display all of the information about the shapes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// Global constant for array size.
const int SIZE = 99;

// Base Class
class Shape
{
protected:
  char type;
  int serNo;
  int dim1;
  int dim2;

public:
  // Default constructor
  Shape()
  {
    type = ' ';
    serNo = 0;
    dim1 = 0;
    dim2 = 0;
  }

  // Constructor #1
  Shape(char t, int s, int d1, int d2)
  {
    type = t;
    serNo = s;
    dim1 = d1;
    dim2 = d2;
  }

  // Get type
  char getType()
  {
    return type;
  }

  // Get serial number
  int getSerNo()
  {
    return serNo;
  }

  // Get dimension1
  int getDim1()
  {
    return dim1;
  }    

  // Get dimension2
  int getDim2()
  {
    return dim2;
  }

  // Destructor
  ~Shape()
  {}
};

// Circle Class (Derived from Shape)
class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
  Circle(char t, int s, int d1, int d2) : Shape(t, s, d1, d2)
  {}

};

// Spray Class (Derived from Circle)
class Spray : public Circle
{
public:
// Constructor
  Spray(char t, int s, int d1, int d2) : Circle(t, s, d1, d2)
  {}

};

// Rectangle Class (Derived from Shape)
class Rectangle : public Shape
{
public:
// Constructor
  Rectangle(char t, int s, int d1, int d2) : Shape(t, s, d1, d2)
  {}

};

// Square Class (Derived from Rectangle)
class Square : public Rectangle
{
public:
// Constructor
  Square(char t, int s, int d1, int d2) : Rectangle(t, s, d1, d2)
  {}

};

class mgrShape : public Shape
{
protected:
  int recordCount;
  Shape * shapeArr[SIZE] = {nullptr}; // Manager owns the main data 
//structure
public:
  // Constructor.
  mgrShape()
  {
    populateShapeData();
  }

  // Populate the shapeArr from file.
  void populateShapeData()
  {
    fstream inputFile;
    string fileName = "shaperecords.txt";
    inputFile.open(fileName);
    while(inputFile >> type >> serNo >> dim1 >> dim2)
    {
      if (type == 'C')
        shapeArr[recordCount] = new Circle(type, serNo, dim1, dim2);
      else if (type == 'R')
        shapeArr[recordCount] = new Rectangle(type, serNo, dim1, dim2);
      else if (type == 'S')
        shapeArr[recordCount] = new Spray(type, serNo, dim1, dim2);
      else if (type == 'Q')
        shapeArr[recordCount] = new Square(type, serNo, dim1, dim2);
      recordCount++;
    }
    inputFile.close();
  }

  //Display all of the shapes.
  void displayAll()
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < recordCount; i++)
    {
      if (shapeArr[i]->getType() == 'C')
      {
        cout << "Circle Found!" << endl;
        cout << shapeArr[i]->getType() << endl;
        cout << shapeArr[i]->getSerNo() << endl;
        cout << shapeArr[i]->getDim1() << endl;
        cout << shapeArr[i]->getDim2() << endl;
      }
      else if (shapeArr[i]->getType() == 'R')
      {
        cout << "Rectangle Found!" << endl;
        cout << shapeArr[i]->getType() << endl;
        cout << shapeArr[i]->getSerNo() << endl;
        cout << shapeArr[i]->getDim1() << endl;
        cout << shapeArr[i]->getDim2() << endl;
      }
      else if (shapeArr[i]->getType() == 'S')
      {
        cout << "\nSpray Found!" << endl;
        cout << shapeArr[i]->getType() << endl;
        cout << shapeArr[i]->getSerNo() << endl;
        cout << shapeArr[i]->getDim1() << endl;
        cout << shapeArr[i]->getDim2() << endl;
      }
      else if (shapeArr[i]->getType() == 'Q')
      {
        cout << "Square Found!" << endl;
        cout << shapeArr[i]->getType() << endl;
        cout << shapeArr[i]->getSerNo() << endl;
        cout << shapeArr[i]->getDim1() << endl;
        cout << shapeArr[i]->getDim2() << endl;
      }
    }
  }

// Clear the dynamically allocated memory from shapeArr.
~mgrShape()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < recordCount; i++)
    delete shapeArr[i];
}

};


int main()
{
  mgrShape ms;

  ms.displayAll();

  return 0;
}





//And here's the input file's contents

//C 1001 30 -1
//R 1002 14 10
//S 1003 30 20
//Q 1004 28 -1
//S 1005 30 75
```

Comment: Please cut and paste the actual errors, and use the debugger within the IDE to narrow down the problem. Also, have you turned on warnings and fixed issues identified by the compiler? Especially any warning about `recordCount` being used before being initialised.

Comment: Do a little more research on OOP. Should `mgrShape` be derived from `Shape`? Inheritance is an "is-a" relationship. Is a `mgrShape` a `Shape`?

Comment: Extending on @MikeBorkland 's comment: Read up on the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). The TL;DR version goes something like "It must makes sense to use the Derived class as an instance of the Base class." In this case it doesn't make sense to use a `Shape` manager as if it was another `Shape`. Likely the relationship you want is one of composition, the manager contains `Shape`s. Another possibility, that doesn't appear to be necessary here, is `friend`ship, the manager can inspect/use the `Shape`'s `private` data.